# React 16 Component Size Attribute (size="test") get removed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Has anyone experienced similar issue which is the size attribute of react component been removed.

For example,

```
`ReactDOM.render(
  <h1 size="hello">Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);`
```

You will see the size="hello" will be removed

According to the article below, "In React 16, we are making a change. Now, any unknown attributes will end up in the DOM:"
https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/08/dom-attributes-in-react-16.html

Does anyone know any react why react 16 is doing this? Many thanks

Comment: [Why are we changing this?](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/08/dom-attributes-in-react-16.html#why-are-we-changing-this) from that very same article?

Answer (score 0):

`size` is a known attribute, therefore it may still be removed if an element (such as `h1`) doesn't support it

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Use a supported element.

```
<input size="10" placeholder="Hello, world!" />
```

2. Use a different name that isn't for a known attribute.

```
<h1 customsize="hello">Hello, world!</h1>
```